# How to remove file on Linux with ? in name

Tags: linux, bash, rm

Cannot move or remove file with ? in name. Any ideas? Have tried the following:

```
# ls
manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html  what-wcsap-can-offer-you-?%80%93-guide-new-directors.html

# mv manager\?%80%99s-viewpoint.html mangers-viewpoint.html
mv: cannot stat ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# rm ./manager\?%80%99s-viewpoint.html 
rm: cannot remove ‘./manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# rm -- 'manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html' 
rm: cannot remove ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# rm -- "manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html" 
rm: cannot remove ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# rm -- manager\?%80%99s-viewpoint.html 
rm: remove regular file ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# rm manager*-viewpoint.html 
rm: remove regular file ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# rm -i manager*-viewpoint.html 
rm: remove regular file ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# ls -i
48374896 manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html
48376904 what-wcsap-can-offer-you-?%80%93-guide-new-directors.html

# find -inum 48374896
./manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html

# find -inum 48374896 -exec rm -i '{}' \;
rm: remove regular file ‘./manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘./manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory

# find -inum 48374896 -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./manager?%80%99s-viewpoint.html’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Doubtful that it is filesystem corruption. I did a wget of a website last night and it created quite a few files in different directories with these bad names. Will try fsck.

Comment: Note that `ls` shows `?` for any unprintable character, so you probably don't have a literal `?` in the file name. You can find out what is really in the file name with `ls -b`, though the display string cannot be used literally in `rm`. You can type `rm manager` and then `Tab`, and this should expand to a usable file name. It might be easiest to locate the file in your GUI file manager and delete from there. I saw your answer, but you should still be able to delete from the VM, assuming you have the permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

OK. My bad. It is a VirtualBox client with the files on the host. When I go to the VB host I can deal with the files as normal. How do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: "You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!" from http://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: You have to go back to the original device you posted the question from. And hope you didn't clear your cookies. Because you posted as guest and didn't finish registering an account.